# What's the proper way to programmatically adjust the Vertical-Space Constraint?

Tags: autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

**Scenario:** Subview programmatically-positioned in a container view. 
**Purpose:** To share an XIB across iphone devices. 
       And Hence, *To Adjust the position of the Subview per target device (3.5" standard vs 4" retina)*.

**Environment:** iOS6/iOS7 Build the initial auto-layout/device within IB; then adjust it (vertical reposition) per device.

I need a way to adjust a particular Vertical-Space constraint per device screen; similar in the way we change the frame in pre-constraints.

**Question:** It appears that I would have to replace the constraint vs change it.  
To do that, I would have to either *identify* the target complaint or *replace ALL* the constraints.

This appears to be very awkward.

**Possible Solution:** adjust the frame coordinates per constraint rules (i.e., have an inequality vertical constraint with associated hugging rules, etc.).

But that seems to counter the purpose of having constraints: to avoid hassling with frames.  But it also seems awkward to having to replace the constraints per device.

Or...

Would it be best to user device-dependent xibs instead?

Example:

standard.xib

four-inch_retina.xib

etc.

The more I think about it, the more it makes sense to keep xibs/devices.

But that would double the number of XIBs, as more devices need to be supported.

Any suggestions?